# Hashicorp Waypoint: entrypoint.url.agent: error in service handler

Tags: hashicorp

I have a very basic Flask app.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Flask application'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Also my Dockerfile is pretty straightforward:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "run.py" ]
```

When I run the app manually, it works. When I use Waypoint it always gives the following error:

> Couldn't find a Waypoint deployment with this URL (see screenshot)

My waypoint.hcl file is as follows:

```
project = "Flask Todo application"

app "flask_todo_app" {
    build {
        use "docker" {}
    }

    deploy {
        use "docker" {}
    }
}
```

The moment I try to go to the displayed deployment URL I get in the logs the following error message:

> [ERROR] entrypoint.url.agent: error in service handler: error="Get "http://:3000/": dial tcp :3000: connect: connection refused"

Answer (score 1):

Based on the docs (link below), you may need to set the PORT environment variable to 3000.

> Proper environment variables must be set so the entrypoint knows how
> to communicate to the Waypoint server. This step happens in this
> deployment stage

https://www.waypointproject.io/plugins/nomad#entrypoint-functionality